# Sobolev's inequality for higher derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is from p.102 of *Sobolev Spaces* by R. Adams and J. Fournier.

[image]

Here $\|\cdot\|_q$ is the $L^q$ norm, $C_0^\infty$ means compactly supported and $C^\infty$, and $$|\phi|_{m,p}:=\bigg(\sum_{|\alpha|=m}\int|D^\alpha\phi(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\bigg)^{1/p}.$$

I know the proof for $m=1$, which is standard and can be found in many books. However don't know how to do the induction on $m$. In the process we must use $mp<n$, but I don't see how... Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/Sobolev%20Inequalities.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do the induction step.  Suppose that if $1\le m$ is an integer and $1 \le p$ is such that $m p < n$, then there exists $K = K(m,p) >0$ such that if $q = np/(n-mp)$ then
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{L^q} \le K \vert u \vert_{m,p} \text{ for all } u \in C^\infty_0.
$$
Further suppose that $p \ge 1$ is such that $(m+1) p < n$ and note in particular that this implies two important bounds: first, $m p < (m+1) p < n$, and second 
$$
p < n-mp \Rightarrow q_0 = \frac{np}{n-mp} < n.
$$
Fix $u \in C^\infty_0$.  We then apply the induction hypothesis for each $1 \le j \le n$ to see that 
$$
\Vert \partial_j u \Vert_{L^{q_0}} \le K(m,p) \vert \partial_j u \vert_{m,p} \le K(m,p) \vert u \vert_{m+1,p}. 
$$
Summing over $j$, we find that 
$$
\vert u \vert_{1,q_0} \le n K \vert u \vert_{m+1,p}. 
$$
In turn, the bound on $q_0$ allows us to apply the base case analysis with $m=1$ to see that 
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{L^{q}} \le K(1,q_0)  \vert u \vert_{1,q_0} \le n K(1,q_0) K(m,p) \vert u \vert_{m+1,p} =: K(m+1,p) \vert u \vert_{m+1,p}
$$
for 
$$
q = \frac{n q_0}{n- q_0} = \frac{n^2 p}{n-mp} \frac{n-mp}{n^2 -np(m+1)} = \frac{np}{n - (m+1)p},
$$
which is what we were after.